# How to use the same colorbar for seaborn heatmaps?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

I have three subplots which have slightly different colorbars when plotted individually

I plotted the heatmaps as follows:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize = (20,10),sharey=True)

sns.heatmap(df,cmap=colormap,ax = axes[0])
sns.heatmap(df2,cmap=colormap,ax = axes[1])
sns.heatmap(df3,cmap=colormap,ax = axes[2])
```

I know that I can just set `cbar = False` for the first two plots, however as they are slightly different colorbars, the third colour bar will not represent all subplots. My first subplot ranges from 0-35, the second 0-36 and the third 0-37. I want a colorbar that encompasses the 0-37 range but obviously the colors will correspond to the wrong values for the first two subplots if I just do `cbar = False`.

How would I set up my subplots to contain just one colorbar which applies to all subplots, instead of three? Sorry about the lack of figures, I am unable to share them at this stage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want a colorbar that encompasses the 0-37 range but obviously the colors will correspond to the wrong values for the first two subplots if I just do `cbar=False`.

In addition to setting `cbar=False` on the first two heatmaps, anchor all the heatmaps to the same colormap range:

- Either set `vmin` and `vmax` on each heatmap:

  ```
  sns.heatmap(df,  ax=axes[0], vmin=0, vmax=37, cbar=False)
  sns.heatmap(df2, ax=axes[1], vmin=0, vmax=37, cbar=False)
  sns.heatmap(df3, ax=axes[2], vmin=0, vmax=37)
  #                            ^       ^
  ```
- Or create a min/max `norm` using [`matplotlib.colors.Normalize`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Normalize.html#matplotlib.colors.Normalize):

  ```
  import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
  norm = mcolors.Normalize(0, 37)

  sns.heatmap(df,  ax=axes[0], norm=norm, cbar=False)
  sns.heatmap(df2, ax=axes[1], norm=norm, cbar=False)
  sns.heatmap(df3, ax=axes[2], norm=norm)
  #                            ^
  ```

---

Note that if you want to extract `vmin` and `vmax` automatically, `ravel` and `stack` the data:

```
values = np.hstack([d.values.ravel() for d in [df, df2, df3]])
norm = mcolors.Normalize(values.min(), values.max())
```